# Azure Data Factory dataflow "No space left on device"

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

I am running a pipeline in Azure Data Factory with a dataflow with some sources and transformations, but the pipeline runs for around 40 hrs and then fail with the error:

[image]

There is a way that I can debug the reason of this error? or what it means with "No space left on device"?

The data used are located in a datalake and then trying to sink into a Azure Synapse DB.

Thanks

Comment: Ran out of (disk or quota) storage..

Comment: Just out of interest, why are you using Data Flows to load data into Synapse?  As your data is already in Data Lake, could you use Polybase, Synapse COPY command or even SQL on-demand?

Comment: ran out of disk quota? in the datalake?, no I have sufficient storage.

Comment: i am using data flows to transform the data and then sink into Synapse the result dataset.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Spark error coming from the working happening behind the scenes. As this is an uncaught exception, I would recommend opening an Azure support ticket so that our engineers can get to the root cause for you.

The root cause here is likely the worker filling up due to job taking so long. To avoid this, I would recommend implementing [performance best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-performance) to reduce the length of the job as 40 hrs is far too long.

Thanks,
Daniel